# Capture screenshot from Webcam using DirectX.Capture class [VB/C#]

Tags: c#, vb.net, directx, capture

i'm using the "DirectX Capture class library" to capture my webcam and make video and screenshot.

Here the link of the class library: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3566/DirectX-Capture-Class-Library

For capturing devices and record videos, it's all ok!
But i can't find any guide or command to take a screenshot of my webcam.

How can i do?
What can i write to add the "screenshot" method to this class for retreive the current frame as Bitmap?

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is follow up work on the library you use, which allows you to capture a frame from camera:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4740/Capture-Sample-with-DirectX-and-NET